# Regex to remove spaces inside quoted text

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove all white space only within quoted sections of a string.

Give this:
`10 00,400,"a1 b2 c3 ",zz xx,100`

I need this: 
`10 00,400,"a1b2c3",zz xx,100`

Obviously, restricting it to quoted areas only is why I'm having trouble.

The strings will vary in length and can have multiple quoted sections.

Comment: Do you **have** to use a regex?

Comment: No, but it would be a lot easier if I could due to some limiting environment factors.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of non-space sections within the quotes?  As in the example, will it always be 3 sections of text within the quotes?

Comment: something like `((^|,)\")(.+?)?\s+(.+?)?(?=\"($|,))`

Comment: @Sheriff no limit, it could be anything =(

Comment: Is `String.split("\"")` right out?  because then you could just do a `String.replaceAll(" ", str)` with str being the odd numbered entries.

Comment: Regex highly preferred, but will find a way if I have no other choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the quotes are balanced, then you could implement a method like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "10 00,400,\"a1 b2 c3 \",zz xx,100, \"a b\"";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"").matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group().replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

This prints:

```
10 00,400,"a1b2c3",zz xx,100, "ab"
```

Comment: Hmm, it's cutting off the last of the string when using input that does not end in a quote. What's the most elegant way to access the last "delimiter" in that match buffer?

Comment: I suppose I could just add `""` to the end of the string before parsing.

Comment: This `10 400,"a1 b2",500` will become `10 400,"alb2"`

Comment: You may need to count the number of quotes for to know whether the quotes are balanced. You could use `StringUtils.countMatches(input, "\"")` or `Pattern.compile("\\\"").matcher(input).groupCount()`. For the last quote you can use `input.lastIndexOf('"')`. Consider having unique references of `Pattern` to avoid _compile_ the regex every time.

Comment: Cutting with `input = input.substring(0, input.lastIndexOf('"') >= 0 ? input.lastIndexOf('"') + 1 : input.length());`

Comment: I would rather that the final append be bound to the regex, in case the logic changes. lastIndexOf('"') seems sort of a hack. But I'm not complaining. ;)

Comment: AH! `matcher.appendTail(sb);`

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't use regex - but works

```
public String replaceWithinQuotes(String input) {
    String[] output = input.split("\"");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for ( int i =0; i < output.length-1; i++ ) {
        if ( i %2 == 0 ) {
            builder.append(output[i]);
        } else {
            builder.append(output[i].replaceAll("[ ]+", ""));
        }
        builder.append("\"");
    }
    builder.append(output[output.length-1]);
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Note - If you are using this - make sure length of the array is **odd**. If it is not, then you have unbalanced quotes and you have to handle that in whatever way is appropriate for your application.

Comment: The function is unaware of whether it's *inside* a quoted section. It only knows it found a quote.

Comment: @DanielE - It replaces only the "odd" entries - so it is inside. However, you need to add error handling for unbalanced quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small routine that seems to work just fine when there is a single set of quotes in the text:

```
public static String cropSpacesWithinQuotes(String expression) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"[\\S*\\s\\S*]*\"");
    StringBuilder noSpaces=new StringBuilder();
    int initialPosition=0;
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(expression);
    while (matcher.find(initialPosition)) {
            int pos=matcher.start();
            noSpaces.append(expression.substring(initialPosition, pos-initialPosition));
            initialPosition=matcher.end();
            noSpaces.append(matcher.group().replaceAll(" ", ""));
    }
    noSpaces.append(expression.substring(initialPosition));
    return(noSpaces.toString());
}
```

Performing some unit tests I realized that when there is more that one pair of quotes the text within the two sets also has its spaces cropped. Some manipulation on the variable initialPosition should solve your problem.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah that's one of the problems I was having trying to get this into a one line regex.